# How to test a variable is null in python

Tags: python

```
val = ""

del val

if val is None:
    print("null")
```

I ran above code, but got `NameError: name 'val' is not defined`.

How to decide whether a variable is null, and avoid NameError?

Comment: You could use a `try : except` block to check if the error is being thrown

Comment: That's not a "null" variable - the variable **doesn't exist**... there's a distinct difference between something not existing and existing with a "null" value (in Python that's normally the `None` singleton)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Testing for name pointing to `None` and name existing are two semantically different operations.

To check if `val` is None:

```
if val is None:
    pass  # val exists and is None
```

To check if name exists:

```
try:
    val
except NameError:
    pass  # val does not exist at all
```

Answer (score 14):

```
try:
    if val is None: # The variable
        print('It is None')
except NameError:
    print ("This variable is not defined")
else:
    print ("It is defined and has a value")
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in a try and catch block:

```
try:
    if val is None:
        print("null")
except NameError:
    # throw an exception or do something else
```